# Power management failure and /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: nvidia, sudo, power-management

A few days age I purchased a new laptop, Asus X751MD, and I installed the 64 bit Kubuntu version of 14.10. After installing some programs and restarting the computer, I got the power management failure, stating that I have to reinstall the system, which I did two times and got the same problem every time.

Also I am unable to use `sudo` and I get this message:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

This laptop uses the Nvidia Geforce 610m hybrid graphics and I suspect this has something to do with the graphics, even though I installed bumblebee.

I really have no plan on installing the same system with the same results, so please help me if you can. I really don't want to return to using Windows, but if there is no other solution, I will be forced to.

Thank you in advance.

Mount results:

```
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755,size=1024)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda7 on /usr type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda8 on /usr/local type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
```

I reinstalled it from the DVD burned version of Kubuntu 64bit ISO. I reformatted the entire system and created new partitions.

Comment: This looks fine. What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` and does `df -h` show anywhere more than 90%?

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 151072 авг 28 13:14 /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: no, the largest is 25%

Comment: This is wrong, anyone can change it and therefore it lost setuid bit. Have you changed permissions in `/usr/bin`? What does `ls -ld /usr/bin` return?

Comment: I have installed the root menu for Dolphin and I made all partitions writable with the menu. This is the output: drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 49152 феб 13 22:45 /usr/bin

Comment: Well, that is what has broken your system. Why do you want to make it all writable?

Comment: I only wanted to make my two larger partitions writable, but it seems I overdid it. I guess it's my old habits from Windows. I'm still new to Kubuntu.

Comment: are you sure it has nothing to do with the nvidia drivers?

Comment: If you want to use the free space, use single file system. Unless using multiple disks, there is only seldom a need to have more (but you still should have a partition for swap). The nVidia driver has nothing to do with the `sudo` error and probably not even with the power management failure but to be sure you would need to post the failure message.

Comment: The message appeared at startup, "KDE Power Management System could not be initialized. The backend reported the following error: No valid Power Management backend plugins are available. A new installation might solve this problem. Please check your system configuration."

Comment: This is most probably also caused by changing the privileges. You can confirm it if `/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` is missing setuid flag.

Comment: it says dbus-daemon-activation-helper service.to.activate

Comment: Could you post `ls -l /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper`? But it seems it is broken because you should not be able to call it.

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root messagebus 294512 нов 25 21:37 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper

Comment: Yes, it misses the setuid flag which is why power management is not working.

Comment: So I should install a new system and it should work fine if I don't change root privileges?

Comment: You can continue to use it but there will be a lot of functionality broken. I would reinstall the system.

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you very much for your help. :-)

Comment: @StenSoft: Could you please convert your last comment "reinstall due to broken security settings" to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: Added the answer. I have also included possibility to restore the system when installed on btrfs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have changed permissions of files in `/usr/bin`. Some of these files need setuid bit (the file is run under the account of the file's owner which is root in `/usr/bin`) to work properly but by setting write bit to anyone else than the owner, this would create a massive security hole (anyone could change the content and run it as root), therefore setting the write bit removes the setuid bit.

Unless you have btrfs with APT snapshotting, it is quite hard to determine what were the original permissions of the files in `/usr/bin`, you would basically need to reinstall all packages and it still may not set everything correctly. Therefore the easiest solution here is to reinstall the system as a whole.

If you do have btrfs with APT snapshotting (should be automatically enabled if you use btrfs for your system) and `/usr` or `/usr/bin` is not on a separate partition, it is possible to revert to an older snapshot where this change was not done yet. This can be done with the command `apt-btrfs-snapshot` in rescue mode (selected in GRUB):

```
# List all available snapshots
apt-btrfs-snapshot list

# Revert to a selected snapshot
apt-btrfs-snapshot set-default @apt-snapshot-YYYY-MM-DD_HH:mm:ss

# Reboot to load the old system
reboot
```